# Operating system in Java Language (JVM)

Tags: java, operating-system, jvm, system

Just a simple Q. It is possible to code OS in Java? If yes, how I can i run Java via Assembly? Or how exactly it works.

Comment: You can write an OS in .NET (e.g., [Singularity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/singularity/), [Renraku](https://github.com/daeken/RenrakuOS)), so at least some of the concepts should be transferrable to the JVM.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple projects trying to do that see [JavaOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS), [JNode](http://www.jnode.org/), [JOS](http://jos.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, Its possible.**
Please check [JOS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jos/) a free and open Java(tm) based Operating System (JOS). 
You can take a help from  http://www.jnode.org/.

Comment: So i need just run JVM via c++?

Comment: Why you need c++? You need JDK to compile classes and JRE to run the same.

Comment: And how can I run JRE in my OS?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible, and has been done.  Tipically, you would write the kernel (or microkernel) as an extended Java virtual machine, with all the rest of the system (which could include process management, network stack, etc.) being written in pure Java.

Among the many pros of this approach there is the so called [language-based protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language-based_system): Java is a type-safe system, hence (ideally, at least) you don't need to use hardware memory protection to provide isolation between processes.

Take a look, for example, at the [JX Project](http://www4.cs.fau.de/Projects/JX/index.html).